# Searching for an element in a 3d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello I was just wondering if anyone would know how the best way to search a three dimensional array for a specific name?
Thank you very much

```
var players=[["Patrick mahomes","QB",99],["Arron donald","DT",98],["Tyreek hill","Wr",98],["Lamar jackson","Qb",94]]
const value = players.includes("Patrick mahomes")
console.log(value)
```

Comment: you have only 2d. what result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It is a 2d array and you can use `find` and `includes`, to get the array which contain the searched value. Alternatively you can also use `some` and `includes` if you just want to know if the searched text is available in any of the nested array

```js
var players = [
  ["Patrick mahomes", "QB", 99],
  ["Arron donald", "DT", 98],
  ["Tyreek hill", "Wr", 98],
  ["Lamar jackson", "Qb", 94]
]
const value = players.find(item => item.includes('Patrick mahomes'));
console.log(value);
const isAvail = players.some(item => item.includes('Patrick mahomes'));
console.log(isAvail)
```